# R force print before function is run

Tags: r, printing

I have a small bit of code that I want to print into the console before it runs so that the user will know what to do

```
if(Save_Data == "y"){
    print("Please select the file folder where you would like the information to be populated")
    file = choose.dir()
    file.dir=dirname(file)
}
```

is there any way for the code to print in the console before `choose.dir()` is run?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - this does print the message before `choose.dir` runs.

Comment: I'm running this on R console, and it's not working on my end

Comment: Okay I see what you are saying now. The behavior in RStudio is different.

Comment: I'm trying to make sure this will be able to run no matter what program this runs on, as I am not sure who will be using this code after I am done.

Comment: Understood; it's a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly flush the console if you want the message to reliably appear prior to the dialog box

```
flushdemo<-function() 
{
  cat("Please select the file folder where you would like the information to be populated\n")
  flush.console()
  file <- choose.dir()
  return(file)
}

flushdemo()
```

Comment: would someone running Rstudio still see it normally?

Comment: @MikeJewski This works in RStudio; I just tested it.

Comment: I'm on a Mac (so can't use `choose.dir()`), but i face a similar problem with `file.choose()`. This solution is unnecessary from the terminal and does not work in RStudio. Can something more general be done?